# Does the re-use of HTML email newsletter content for blog posts have SEO (or other) repercusions?

Tags: html, blog, automation, newsletter

I am (in parallel) building both a newsletter subscriber list (using Mailchimp) and also a blog website (using Wordpress). I want to be as efficient as possible with the use of my content / copy. I would like to send out newsletters to subscribers first and then re-use the content for time delayed blog postings. Using a Wordpress plugin such as 'postie' I can easily send an email directly to my website that is then entered into my blog post stream automatically. If I prepare the styling of my email appropriately in Mailchimp, the posting should look like native content on my website.

However, my current understanding is that robust HTML emails tend to use A LOT of tables to force the email client to render the email correctly. Also, they tend to use A LOT of inline CSS and the like. If I simply insert this into my blog stream the website HTML is going to get 'ugly' and likely slow to load.

But, does this actually matter?
Will webcrawlers & search engines have a tantrum?

If I need to avoid this scenario, should I search for a solution (hopefully not manual re-coding) that creates two versions of the HTML: one for newsletter use; one for blog stream insertion?

I really want to avoid the manual effort of having to create two versions of the HTML content from scratch each time.

Answer (score 1):

Many SEO experts say that the primary factors for a good ranking are:

- the quality of the actual content (not the coding style)
- and the number of good backlinks.

I let you search for the detailed criteria. Thus, technical considerations, like page loading, are secondary. You should go and publish the newsletters as they are, if you don't want to recode the HTML/CSS.

You should also search for an online HTML-beautifier/simplifier/cleaner website and do some tests.